# Formatting Generated XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, transformer-model

I have a generated xml using the Transformer to do the actual writing (to a StreamResult). I am trying to have it nicely generated that is more human-readable. I have inserted the code below and it does the indentation for me.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

However, in such cases where I have attributes in a element like:

```
<ElementA name="foo" description="bar" value="xyz"></ElementA>
```

How can I make it to look like the one below and having the attribute listed in the order that I set them in the code using elementA.setAttribute("name", "foo"); Currently it reorders itself according to alphabetical order:

```
<ElementA name="foo"
          description="bar"
          value="xyz">

</ElementA>
```

Comment: As far as I know the option to format attributes is not available... if you want to format that way import it into an XML editor (like eclipse) and perform formatting there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using XSLT.  They have an example [here](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2004k/ctl257/JavaXSLT/Ch05.html).

Comment: The link points to very general tutorial of the XSLT, it might help to either add more specific link, or to include the example in the answer itself. All in all, XSLT looks like a good idea.